# localize the backend based on the request from the frontend

Tags: node.js, localization, internationalization, i18next

I have a web application with reactjs+node. Users can choose their language for the interface of the frontend. We use `i18next` to manage that in the frontend.

When a user sends a request, e.g., registering an account, from the frontend to the backend, we would like to pass a `lang` parameter as well. This will be used to determine the language in which the verification email to the user will be. For instance, in general all the messages from the backend are in English. If `lang` is `zh`, we will send messages such as verification emails in Chinese.

At the moment, I have the following `i18next-config.js`:

```
var i18next = require('i18next');
var Backend = require('i18next-fs-backend');

i18next.use(Backend)
  .init({
    lng: "en",
    fallbackLng: "en",
    preload: ["en", "zh"], // load languages
    ns: ["translation"],
    defaultNS: "translation",
    backend: {
      loadPath: "./locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json", // Path where resources get loaded from
      // addPath: "./locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.missing.json", // Path to post missing resources
    },
    debug: true,
  });

module.exports = i18next;
```

The following `locales/zh/translation.json`:

```
{ "validate_this_email" : "确认此邮箱" }
```

and `locales/en/translation.json`:

```
{ "validate_this_email" : "Validate this email" }
```

And registrering an account calls the following `sendMailVerification` function. I made a test with `zh` as `language`:

```
sendMailVerification (email, name, codeVerification, msg, language) {
    var i18n = i18nOriginal.cloneInstance({ lng: language })
    console.log("validate_this_email", i18n.t("validate_this_email"));
    const linkVerification = `${process.env.signDomain}/${process.env.versionNumber}/auth/verification/${codeVerification}`;
    emailService.sendMail({
      to: email,
      subject: 'Verification Email',
      text: `Go to this link to confirm: ${linkVerification}`,
      html: makeRegistrationEmail(linkVerification, i18n.t("validate_this_email")),
      category: 'email_verification',
      unique_args: {
        user_email: email,
      },
    });
  }
```

And I got the following error in the backend console. The email sent is still in English.

```
i18next: hasLoadedNamespace: i18next was not initialized undefined
i18next::translator: key "validate_this_email" for languages "en" won't get resolved as namespace "translation" was not yet loaded This means something IS WRONG in your setup. You access the t function before i18next.init / i18next.loadNamespace / i18next.changeLanguage was done. Wait for the callback or Promise to resolve before accessing it!!!
validate_this_email Validate This Email
i18next: languageChanged zh
send mail successfully
```

Does anyone know what's the conventional way to achieve that? Is it a good idea to use `cloneInstance`?

Comment: You may provide more information of your code… but I would personally use i18next-http-middleware like here: https://locize.com/blog/how-does-server-side-internationalization-look-like/#ssr